# Java contains() not in accordance with equals()

Tags: java, equals, contains

I have a custom class with overriden `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. I store instances of that class in a `TreeSet`. I cannot figure out why the `tree.contains(someObject)` returns `true`, while `tree.first().equals(someObject)` returns `false`, in the case when the `tree` has only one element.

Comment: Can you share the object `equals` and `hashCode` please?

Comment: I agree with @Mureinik. Post all relevant code before this question gets closed or voted down  heavily.

Comment: Does your custom class implement `Comparable`, or have you specified a custom `Comparator` for the `TreeSet`?

Comment: @isnot2bad I am not sure what role does `Comparable` and `Comparator` play when using the `contains` method?

Comment: @isnot2bad It does implement `Comparable`, and `compareTo()` is implemented in a way that `tree.first().compareTo(someObject)` returns 0.

Comment: @user3139563 `o1.compareTo(o2)` should return 0 (equality) if `o1.equals(o2)` is `true`. Otherwise two non-equal objects (according to `equals`) are considered equal by the `TreeSet`, which only uses `compareTo(...)` for object comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should **implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)** but you should also **override the `equals`**. **Both are required.**

Further more, you should make sure that the `compareTo` method always returns 0 when the `equals` would return true. If the `equals` would return false, then also the `compareTo` should return a value != 0.

Implementing hashCode is necessary if you wanted to use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead. So, it's probably a good idea to implement it as well.

**EDIT:**

For those who wonder about [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html): This interface is used when you want to use different kinds of sorting from time to time. In that case you create an additional class which acts as a sorter. This class then needs to implement the `Comparator` interface. So in this case you don't want your class to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

As per doc for [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> The Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a
>   TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo
>   (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this
>   method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal.

If you instantiate a TreeSet without an explicit comparator, it expects inserted elements to implement `Comparable`. It seems you have not done that.